# Fragment caching in a rabl view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, rabl

I read [rabl caching doc](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Caching-in-RABL) and I don't get how I can cache fragment of code.
I have a view like this (there more code, but I removed it for simplicity's sake):

```
object @video

attributes :id, :user_id, :event_id

child :event do
  attributes :id
  node(:name) { |event| event.name }
end

child :user do
  attributes :id
end
```

And I want to cache :event child for two hours. How can I do that?

I'm using rabl(0.7.6), rails(3.2.0), ruby(1.9.3p125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [this](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/351) thread, i move :event child to partial and cache this partial.

show.rabl.json:

```
object @video

attributes :id, :user_id, :event_id

child :event do
  extends "event"
end

child :user do
  attributes :id
end
```

event.rabl.json:

```
object @event
cache @event, :expires_in => 2.hour

attributes :id
node(:name) { |event| event.name }
```

And it work good for me.